# Html.ActionLink Javascript in href

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to generate the ActionLink via helper method in the following way:

```
return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, route, attributes);
```

The values that I pass in are the following:

```
new ActionLinkModel
{
    LinkText = "Help",
    ElementId = "HelpLink",
    ActionName = "javascript:void(0);",
    ControllerName = "",
    HtmlAttributes = new {onclick = "RunSomeFunction(this, 'Something');"}
}
```

Essentially the model gets mapped to the values you see in my first line of code.

The output that I get on the HTML page is this:

```
<a href="/MyWebsite/MyController/javascript%3avoid(0)%3b" id="HelpLink" onclick="RunSomeFunction(this, 'Something');">Help</a>
```

I would like the output to be this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="HelpLink" onclick="RunSomeFunction(this, 'Something');">Help</a>
```

How would I accomplish that?  The idea of using the ActionLink helper method as it allows me to loop through menu and print it out and have the menu's be controller by the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to add `href` manually in attribute

```
new ActionLinkModel
{
    LinkText = "Help",
    ElementId = "HelpLink",
    ActionName = "",
    ControllerName = "",
    HtmlAttributes = new {@href="javascript:void(0);",onclick = "RunSomeFunction(this, 'Something');"}
}
```